# Assigning values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please assist me on below coding. I am getting run time error - 13.
What is wrong in my below coding

```
String1 = .Offset(0, 6).Cells.Value


With ws1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    iRow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    With .Range("J1:J" & iRow1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=str
        Dim String1 As String
        String1 = .Offset(0, 6).Cells.Value
        MsgBox String1
    End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Please reformat code so it is more readable.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Criteria1:=str looks wrong. What is str?

Comment: str is the string.  Please confirn if the below code is correct.String1 = .Offset(0, 6).Cells.Value

Answer (score 0):

**.Offset()** should be applied to a *Range* Object